# All Combinations of one Array with 2 connectors

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, combinations

My problem is relatively simple but I cannot figure it out a reasonable algorithm by myself

I have an array which can be any length (n>=2), and I want to connect the elements with 2 separators ( '_' and '+' ):

So for example when my array has 2 elements [0,1] the result would be
`[0_1, 0+1]`

For 3 elements [0,1,2]

```
0_1_2,
0+1+2, 
0+1_2, 
0_1+2,  
0_2+1
```

For 4 elements [0,1,2,3]

```
0_1_2_3,
0+1+2+3, 
0+1_2_3, 
0_1+2_3, 
0_1_2+3, 
0_2+1+3,
0_2+1_3,
0_3+1+2,
0_3+1_2
```

For 5 elements [0,1,2,3,4]

```
0_1_2_3_4, 
0+1_2_3_4, 
0_1+2_3_4, 
0_1_2+3_4,
0_1_2_3+4,  
0+1+2+3+4,
0_2+1+3+4,
0_2+1_3_4,
0_2+1+3_4,
0_2+1_3+4,
...
```

I hope this explanation is somewhat clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this hits spec, but its a start:

```
$new = [];
$arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++) {
    $new[] = implode("_",$arr);
    $arr[] = array_shift($arr);
}

foreach($new as $n) {
    $o = $n;
    while(strpos($o,"_")) {
        $o = preg_replace("/_/","+",$o,1);
        $new[] = $o;
    }

    $o = strrev($n);
    while(strpos($o,"_")) {
        $o = preg_replace("/_/","+",$o,1);
        $new[] = $o;
    }
}

print_r($new);
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.